# Cannot open include file msxml6.h - error, VS2005 c++

Tags: c++, msxml6

I have a fatal error in my c++ VS2005v application.

**cannot open include file msxml6.h. no such file or directory**.

I'm working on server 2008 with VS2005, before I had VS2008 and VS2010 and I've uninstalled both, and reinstall 2005 and **still the error occurred.** I've installed platform sdk for server 2008 and framework 3.5, and SP1. **and still the error occurred.**

NOTE: I see the file in microsoft sdk folders.
**I must use VS2005**

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Add the folder in the include folders list.

Comment: remember to add the SDK include folder to all your project configurations.

Comment: Go to your project's Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General and add the SDK include folder to the Additional Include Directories.